# Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to run Google Dataflow examples using Python SDK.

I am able to run locally:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --output OUTPUT_FILE
```

However when trying to run on GCP:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
    --project myproject \
    --job_name myproject-wordcount \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --staging_location gs://myproject/staging \
    --output gs://myproject/output \
    --network myproject-network \
    --zone europe-west1-b \
    --subnetwork regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/europe-west1 \
    --temp_location gs://myproject/temp
```

I get the following error:

```
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
(9d6636d5e214c789): Workflow failed. Causes: (ab9869cb8161ec27): Error:
 Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.properties.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': ''. Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode.
 HTTP Code: 400
```

I am using apache-beam Python SDK 0.6.0

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have verified that the `--subnetwork` option is not supported by the Pyhton SDK. It should be available in the 2.0.1 release (PR adding it: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3154)

Comment: Can you run the job without that option?

Comment: Thank you @Pablo. The job runs fine locally (without zone, network, subnetwork options). Any ETA on 2.0.1 release?

Comment: @hroussel - for posterity, would you be able to convert your comment to an answer please.

Comment: The 2.0.1 release should be available in a few weeks (4-6 approx). My PR has just been merged, so you can also use the HEAD of the github repo, and this should hopefully work.

Answer (score 2):

add `--subnetwork` with `default` subnetwork fixed my problem:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=my.MainClass \
-Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
--project=my-project \
--stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging \
--gcpTemplateLocation=gs://my-bucket/template \
--templateLocation=gs://my-bucket/template \
--gcpTempLocation=gs://my-bucket/tmp \
--region=us-central1 \
--subnetwork=regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default" \
-P dataflow-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for you but if anyone else is getting the same problem the issue is here:
this line:
`--zone europe-west1-b \`
should just be:
`--region europe-west1 \`